# Refactoring Dart Code into a separate file

Tags: flutter, dart, refactoring, navigation-drawer

I have this code where I have the sidebar (drawer) in my app. I have created a separate file `drawer.dart` which looks somewhat like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DrawerClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrawerClassState createState() => _DrawerClassState();
}

class _DrawerClassState extends State<DrawerClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          DrawerHeader(
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              radius: 30,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.pets,
                size: 60,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text("Home"),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/home");
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.report,
            ),
            title: Text("Report"),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/report");
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.settings,
            ),
            title: Text("Settings"),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now I have three different files: `home.dart` , `report.dart`, `settings.dart`. This refactored code will work perfectly when used in `settings.dart` but not in other two files. Example, if I use this in `report.dart` I'll have to change it's onTap status to `Navigator.pop`. I need to use `drawer.dart` in all the other 3 files changing only the onTap status in every file.

Any help will be appreciated:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is like so.

```
enum ScreenName {
  Home,
  Report,
  Settings,
}
```

Use this `enum` as a property (*parentScreen*) of `DrawerClass` so it knows which screen it is in.

```
class DrawerClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final ScreenName parentScreen;

  const DrawerClass({@required this.parentScreen});

  @override
  _DrawerClassState createState() => _DrawerClassState();
}

class _DrawerClassState extends State<DrawerClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          // other children,
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text("Home"),
            onTap: () {
              if (widget.parentScreen == ScreenName.Home)
                Navigator.pop(context);
              else
                Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/home");
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.report),
            title: Text("Report"),
            onTap: () {
              if (widget.parentScreen == ScreenName.Report)
                Navigator.pop(context);
              else
                Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/report");
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: Text("Settings"),
            onTap: () {
              if (widget.parentScreen == ScreenName.Settings)
                Navigator.pop(context);
              else
                Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/settings");
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then use `DrawerClass` like so. For example, for setting screen -

```
DrawerClass(parentScreen: ScreenName.Settings)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to do the same thing with color&style as well, for example, if the parent screen is home - I want to change it's icon color to `color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary`, it's text style and color to `style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,)` and tileColor to `tileColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor`

Comment: Same for other screens

Comment: @HaardikDharma, you can use the same property (`parentScreen`) to decide which `color` or `style` to be set.

Comment: Can you write down an example? I tried doing what you're saying but couldn't get through

Comment: For example, `Icon(Icons.home, color: widget.parentScreen == ScreenName.Home ? color1 : color2)`

Comment: Thank you so much !